# How to execute single dependent test using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-dependency

I want to execute a single test that is dependent on another test. Let's say for the purpose of the question I have the following tests and one of them is depending on another test. I am using pytest-dependency.

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_one(self):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TestClass::test_one"])
    def test_two(self):
        pass
```

When I run the whole suite everything is working perfectly, but when I try to execute only the test **test_one** it always skips because the first test is not passed. Shouldn't the first test be executed in this case too?

Comment: Because you're using the same name for the two tests?

Comment: This is a bad design, tests should not depend on each other, use fixtures for this purpose

Comment: @PhilippSelenium Could not agree more, but I have a case where every operation takes around 15 min and when you need to write a couple of tests it goes up to an hour. Also, it is not possible to add this operation inside a fixture, because there are other tests that rely on the fact that this operation is not executed.

Comment: What about fixture scoping?

Comment: With `pytest-dependency` this will not work due to its design. I have not tried [pytest-depends](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-depends/) which has a similar goal - maybe it will behave differently.